# The behavior of $\operatorname{rad}(x)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid x\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

Let $$\operatorname{rad}(x)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid x\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$$  denote the product of all prime divisors of a positive integer $x$. For example, we have $rad(10)=\prod_{p|10}p=2×5=10$ and $rad(q)=\prod_{p|q}p=q$ for all prime numbers $q$.

My **question** is about the behavior of $rad(x)=\prod_{p|x}p$ when $x$ goes to infinity.

Comment: What type of behaviour would you like specifically? It should be clear that it is always less than or equal to $x$, and it can always fall as low as $2$ after any number.

Comment: @Interestedstudent: The limit for example and possible bounds good than $x$.

Comment: Quite obviously the function has no limit as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: @user: For the subsequence of primes, it goes to infinity.

Comment: It is unusual to consider infinity as a possible value of a limit, but even this "value" does not hold.

Comment: @Interestedstudent: You have $rad(16)=2<16$.

Comment: Yes, for the subsequence of primes, it goes to infinity. For the subsequence $\{2^n| n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ it is always $2$. For anything else, it is in between $2$ and $x$. I don't really see what your question is.

Comment: @Interestedstudent: I have doubts about your third case.

Comment: any integer is a product of primes. any prime is greater than or equal to 2. The product of things greater than or equal to 2 is greater than or equal to 2. QED.

Comment: @Interestedstudent: The product is not still less than $x$.

Comment: It is. What you are basically doing is taking an integer $x$, decomposing it into its prime factors, and removing all factors that appear more than once, hence getting a result that is less than or equal to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no concisely describable "behavior." As $x$ increases, it will serially encounter integers. Some of those will be square-free, for which $rad(x)=x$, and some of those will be perfect powers of a single prime, for which $rad(x)=rad(p^k)=p$. It will most frequently encounter numbers that are neither square-free nor powers of a single prime, in which case $rad(x)<x$, but will be dependent on the idiosyncratic factorization of $x$, which is not systematic with increasing $x$.

In the first instance, as $x$ goes to infinity, its radical (being $x$ itself) goes to infinity as well. In the second instance, as $x=p^k$ goes to infinity, which is to say as $k$ goes to infinity, its radical remains unchanged at $p$. In the third case, it is hard to say anything at all about the magnitudes of the values that $rad(x)$ might take, save  that those values must by definition be square-free numbers, and that in no case does $rad(x)$ exceed $x$.